# Text questions with multiple choices randomisation

Tags: vba

I have a text file that contains over 11 thousand multiple choice and matching questions. The questions have different sizes, besides having different number of given choices. The following **block** is a sample of matching question with five given choices taken from that text file: 
`Type: MT`
`1) Can you match each of these cities to their location? Drag the cities on the right to match them with the locations on the left.`
`~ Correct. You got all these matches correct.`
`@ Incorrect. You got some of these wrong.`
`a. North = Turin`
`b. Center = Rome`
`c. South = Naples`
`d. Sicily = Palermo`
`e. Sardinia = Cagliari`
Before processing this file into a HTML generating engine, I need to shuffle all those questions, i.e. to randomly change the position of each question as a **block** in the file, so the final product will be extremely unpredictable. Each question number *(as mentioned under Type:)* is insignificant.
I found a Word vba code at this [link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/random-order-selected-paragraphs/71a35a23-00e7-4366-b68e-9dea95258f53), but it does need lots of expert alterations to accommodate variant sizes of questions.

Expert assistance in this matter is deeply appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Reads a bit too much like "please write this for me". Try modifiying the code, then post back *with your code* when you run into specific problems.

Answer (score 1):

First, I agree with Tim Williams in the comments above that this is not exactly the level of specificity that is expected in a StackOverflow posting.

That said, if I were you, I would break this question down into two components.

- First - figure out if there is a text string that can be used to identify the blocks that constitute the "question." For example, if each question starts with "Type:", then you can find the first instance of this in the file, then find the second, and everything between them constitutes a "question". Then, you can place that question in an array.
- Second - randomize the array. There are probably a ton of ways to do this. One might be to use a randbetween function between 0 and the length of the array of questions twice, and switch the questions for each of the random numbers. Then, repeat that a number of times relative to the total number of items in the array (for example, if you have 100 questions, perform the "switch" 125 times to sufficiently randomize the output. Then print the array back to the original file.

For the approach above, you need some delimiter in your file (I assumed the delimiter was "Type:") to break the questions above. If a delimiter like this doesn't exist, you may need some more complicated logic.

Comment: Thank you very much Kusha for your answer which puts me forward towards the right solution. I also thank Tim for his comment, but I didn't mean to have it written for me as much as a problem to be thought about. Once I get to the right code, I will post it for everyone.

Comment: No problem. One other thing to think about - if you do decide to choose a delimiter like "Type:", make sure that it is specific enough that it doesn't appear in the text of your questions. If that occurs, you might end up with what should be one question broken up into two entries in the array, which would make the output very confusing. For code review purposes, it might be smart to save the output of the unrandomized array (after step 1 but before step 2 above) so that you can make sure that the parsing of the questions worked as designed.